# Should we be using UIView or UIViewController for the following feature?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

We have the following app, where user can switch to different "page" (purple, yellow, ... colours) from side menu.

[image]

I was wondering, should the "page" be implemented as `UIView`, or should the "page" be implemented as `UIViewController`?

The pages shall responsible to

- Read/ write from/ to CoreData.
- Possible holding a `UIPageView`, which user can swipe through multiple child pages as shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0oNo.gif
- Holding a `UICollectionView`.
- User can drag and move the items in the `UICollectionView`
- User can perform various contextual action (Delete, clone, ...) on the items in `UICollectionView`.
- Can easily port to iPad in the future.

Currently, my implementation of using `UIView` are as follow.

```
private func archive() {
    if let trashView = self.trashView {
        trashView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.trashView = nil
    }
    
    if self.archiveView != nil {
        return
    }
    
    let archiveView = ArchiveView.instanceFromNib()
    
    self.view.addSubview(archiveView)
    archiveView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    archiveView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    archiveView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    archiveView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    archiveView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    self.archiveView = archiveView
}

private func trash() {
    if let archiveView = self.archiveView {
        archiveView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.archiveView = nil
    }
    
    if self.trashView != nil {
        return
    }
    
    let trashView = TrashView.instanceFromNib()
    
    self.view.addSubview(trashView)
    trashView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    trashView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    trashView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    trashView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    trashView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    self.trashView = trashView
}
```

I notice that if I implement the "pages" using `UIView`, I will lost some capability of `UIViewController` like

- `viewDidLoad` callback.
- `viewWillLoad` callback.
- `viewDidLayoutSubviews` callback.
- ...

However, I am not clear whether losing those capabilities will stop me from implementing a proper "page"?

May I know, should I implement those "pages" using `UIView`, or using `UIViewController`?

Comment: Just personal preference, but I'd prefer UIViewController

Comment: I usually just use UIViewController for views that will take up a big portion of the screen, and UIView for views that are small.

Comment: @aheze Thanks. Do you see any problem of implementing the "page" using/ not using UIViewController?

Comment: The first bullet point did it for me - UIViewController. (I'm also doing this - a side panel this way - because of the `UIViewController` lifecycle versus the `UIView`.) But seriously, `UIKit` is almost design as "by the book" MVC, and why should a `UIView care about whether you are using `CoreData` or some other way of saving state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with `UIViewController` because of all the UIKit callback reasons you listed in the question already.

I assume that you have a `UINavigationController` instance that's set as `window.rootViewController` for your app. You have a reference to this instance using which you can easily switch between different screens.

#### Example

```
class SlideMenuViewController: UIViewController {
    enum Option {
        case archive
        case trash
    }
    
    var onSelect: ((_ option: Option) -> Void)?
}

class ArchiveViewController: UIViewController {}
class TrashViewController: UIViewController {}

class AppNavigator {
    
    let mainNavigationController: UINavigationController
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.mainNavigationController = navigationController
    }
    
    private lazy var slideMenuVC: SlideMenuViewController = {
        let slideMenu = SlideMenuViewController()
        slideMenu.onSelect = { [weak self] (option) in
            self?.openScreen(for: option)
        }
        return slideMenu
    }()
    
    private lazy var archiveVC: ArchiveViewController = {
        return ArchiveViewController()
    }()
    
    private lazy var trashVC: TrashViewController = {
        return TrashViewController()
    }()
    
    func openScreen(for option: SlideMenuViewController.Option) {
        let targetVC: UIViewController
        switch option {
        case .archive: targetVC = archiveVC
        case .trash: targetVC = trashVC
        }
        mainNavigationController.setViewControllers([targetVC], animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I totally misunderstood your question, but your UIView should only hold logic related to how the view itself will appear to the user. The UIView should not contain any logic related to the other views or to the model.

UIKit assumes that you use the MVC model to implement apps on the Apple platforms. This means that any code related to controlling which view has to appear and which data the view should get from the model, should be written in the ViewController.

In Xcode you have both the UICollectionViewController and the UIPageViewController to implement page swipes and dragging an dropping views.

View controllers can give the control to other view controllers to present views. The view controller also determine the data that should be presented by the view. Please, check out [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/displaying_and_managing_views_with_a_view_controller) about the MVC model.